# find records by criteria and select only one if they have some equal field (LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a class `BaseEvent` and it have the following fields:

```
Name, RecurrenceStart, RecurrenceEnd, SimillarId
```

For example we have a data in a table:

```
Name           RecurrenceStart                RecurrenceEnd          SimillarId 
Event1      2012-02-21 09:00:00.000      2012-02-28 11:30:00.000        1
Event1      2012-02-21 04:30:00.000      2012-02-28 07:00:00.000        1
Event2      2012-02-21 06:30:00.000      2012-02-29 09:00:00.000        2
```

And we have the following query:

```
   var today = DateTime.Now;
    return  Database.BaseEvents.Where(e => e.RecurrenceStart.Value.Date <= today 
             && e.RecurrenceEnd.Value.Date >= today).ToList();
```

The query return all 3 records(for current date). But the first two record is the same event.
I want that in the result will only two records: 3 and (1 or 2).
How can I do this?
Thanks.

**P.S.** I was introduce SimillarId for this purpose, but I don't know how to build a query with it or not.

**P.S.2.** Change question name if it necessery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.Distinct()` with an `IEqualityComparer<BaseEvent>` as argument which you have to implement first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var today = DateTime.Now; 
    return  Database.BaseEvents.Where(e => e.RecurrenceStart.Value.Date <= today  
             && e.RecurrenceEnd.Value.Date >= today)
            .GroupBy(v => v.Name).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

Comment: For `Distinct` to work you will need to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` on the object. I don't know if this is feasible for you.